# How to change bottom navigation icon color if I change Fragment programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, colors, bottomnavigationview

I am using bottom navigation to change fragments. For whatever reason, I need to change Fragment if the user taps a particular button. This method working fine, except a little aesthetic problem. If I change fragment programmatically, the bottom navigation icon color won't change.

For handling color change, I am using selector XML right now, but I am ready to use other solutions, to handle this little problem.

Comment: `This method working fine` -> which method? :) Are you *telling* the BottomNavBar to select a specific item, or are you manually performing a FragmentTransaction to replace the content?

Comment: Post your selector

Comment: @Martin in that sentence i meant method as a process. So basically it is working if i tap the bottom menu. The problem is if i change the fragment progmatically. So if i replace the fragment from the fragment progmatically

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti my selector working fine. It changes the color if i tap the bottom nav view. Please read my previous comment.

Comment: @csirkeautomata if you don't inform the bottomnavbar that you want to change fragments, it will not change the selected item state. The bar doesn't care what the content is, it just knows what content to put (because you define it declaratively in the XML); it doesn't work the way you think, if you want the correct behavior you have to tell the bottom bar to "select" a "tab".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow this code, it may help you bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);

Comment: Will this method automatically change the color of the selected and the deselected icon as well?

Comment: yes, it will change the color of the selected and deselected icon.